# ruby 3.3.0 installation failing with asdf

Tags: ruby, macos, asdf

when I try to install ruby 3.3.0 version on mac with asdf manager it fails.
psych: Could not be configured. It will not be installed, BUILD FAILED (macOS 14.2.1 on arm64 using ruby-build 20240119)

error:

```
==> Installing ruby-3.3.0...
ruby-build: using gmp from homebrew
-> ./configure "--prefix=$HOME/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.3.0" --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 --enable-shared --with-gmp-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/gmp --with-ext=openssl,psych,+
-> make -j 10
*** Following extensions are not compiled:
psych:
    Could not be configured. It will not be installed.
    Check /var/folders/9d/t29qflyd5jx0c7pn5mdpn2040000gn/T/ruby-build.20240120105143.11952.M2QG45/ruby-3.3.0/ext/psych/mkmf.log for more details.

BUILD FAILED (macOS 14.2.1 on arm64 using ruby-build 20240119)
```

I am using

```
asdf version
v0.14.0-ccdd47d
```

```
brew -v     
Homebrew 4.2.4
```

Mac
 `Darwin Kernel Version 23.2.0: Wed Nov 15 21:53:18 PST 2023; root:xnu-10002.61.3~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64`

more details:

```
~$: cat /var/folders/9d/t29qflyd5jx0c7pn5mdpn2040000gn/T/ruby-build.20240120105143.11952.M2QG45/ruby-3.3.0/ext/psych/mkmf.log

~$:
pkg_config: checking for pkg-config for yaml-0.1... -------------------- not found

package configuration for yaml-0.1 is not found
--------------------

find_header: checking for yaml.h... -------------------- no

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:../.. "clang -o conftest -I../../.ext/include/arm64-darwin23 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/psych -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wmisleading-indentation -Wundef -fno-common -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L../.. -L. -fstack-protector-strong -L/opt/homebrew/opt/gmp/lib  -arch arm64   -lruby.3.3-static -framework CoreFoundation -ldl -lobjc -lpthread   -lpthread  "
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lpthread'
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return !!argv[argc];
6: }
/* end */

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:../.. "clang -I../../.ext/include/arm64-darwin23 -I../.././include -I../.././ext/psych -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -fdeclspec -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wextra-tokens -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wdiv-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-cast-function-type -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wmisleading-indentation -Wundef -fno-common -pipe -arch arm64  -c conftest.c"
conftest.c:3:10: fatal error: 'yaml.h' file not found
#include <yaml.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: #include <yaml.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: I am trying a fresh installation on Mac M2 Pro with os version 14.2.1
Steps I followed
1.  `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`

  2.  `brew install coreutils curl git`

  3.  `git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.14.0`

  4.  ` "$HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh"`

  5.  `asdf install ruby 3.3.0`

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you it can't find `yaml.h`. Is libyaml installed? You can try this per this link: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/discussions/2012

```
brew reinstall libyaml
gem install psych -- --with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml)
export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS=--with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml)
asdf install ruby 3.3.0
```

Comment: libyml was missing.
`brew install libyaml` resolved the problem in my system.